# Why is int8_t read as a character?

Tags: c++

I wanted to put some small integers into an array and decided to use `int8_t`:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    int8_t arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    }
}
```

Input is `9 -20 14` and `n = 3`.

But instead of `9, -20, 14` in array I got `9, -, 2`.

Why does `int8_t` act like a `char`?

P.S. `int8_t` is typedef'd in `sys/types.h` this way:

```
# define __intN_t(N, MODE) \
  typedef int int##N##_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (MODE)))

# ifndef __int8_t_defined
#  define __int8_t_defined
__intN_t (8, __QI__);
# endif
```

Comment: because it is a `typedef` to `signed char` in this case

Comment: Actually I think it should be `signed char` (on almost all platforms), which is distinct type from just `char` (even if on many platforms `char` is signed, in which case they are in that sense identical).

Comment: @hyde `std::ostream` handle all three the same way I believe

Comment: @hyde - the same thing with signed char

Comment: Don't spam tags! C++ is not C is not C++. And provide a [mcve]. You might want to use the C++ header.

Comment: @Slava - I don't see `char` in `typedef` above

Comment: @A.Yurchenko standard defines only those integral types (char short int long and long long), others are aliases. Which way it is done in system headers is irrelevant.

Comment: @Slava: Actually, they don't have to be. `int8_t` can be an alias of `char`, but it is not *required* to be. It can be an compiler-defined type.

Comment: Is that the *only* (potential) definition of `int8_t`? Double check the preprocessor conditionals.

Comment: @Slava - you were right. Should i just delete the question or you will answer it?

Comment: @NicolBolas does it mean if I define a function overrides that accept `char`, `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long` they may fail to accept `int8_t`?

Comment: @Slava: Yes, that's correct. Then again, those overloads would probably fail with `unsigned short` too. Or at least potentially do the wrong thing.

Comment: @NicolBolas so there is no way to have override that would handle that type properly? Unsigned is different story. Sounds incorrect, can you point to standard?

Comment: @Slava: First, `virtual` functions are "overridden". The word you're looking for is "overload". Second, if you want an overload to handle all integer types, you should use the biggest available integer type (`std::intmax_t`) and allow implicit conversions to upscale the integer to that. Or use a template function. You cannot assume that overloading on all of the fundamental integer types is sufficient to capture all integers.

Comment: @NicolBolas "You cannot assume that overloading on all of the fundamental integer types is sufficient to capture all integers." I would like to see that in standard, is there already such question on SO or I should create one?

Comment: @Slava: You've got that backwards. You won't find it in the standard because the standard doesn't provide a guarantee on this. That is, it never says that the fundamental integer types are the *only* integer types a compiler supports. So there is nothing that can be pointed to in the standard; this conclusion is based on the *lack* of such a statement in the standard.

Comment: @NicolBolas I created new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552514/is-overloading-on-all-of-the-fundamental-integer-types-is-sufficient-to-capture let's continue there